# Android Organise Layouts into Sub Folders

Tags: android, layout

I have a fairly complex android app, the contents of the 'layout' folder is becoming increasingly large. I've tried to organise the individual layout xml files into sub folders e.g. layout/buttons/, layout/activity/, layout/views/ etc. This doesn't seem to work, the content of the folders in not parsed into the R. class.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can the Android Layout folder contain subfolders?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4930398/can-the-android-layout-folder-contain-subfolders)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I don't think you're going to be able to do this. I believe that it only supports certain folder names like layout-large, 
layout-mdpi, layout-hdpi, layout-fr, etc. You can use more than one of these modifies as well like layout-fr-hdpi-large.

This page shows all of the allowed modifiers

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: He is talking about subfolders, e.g. `layout-hdpi/buttons/mybutton.xml`, not the resource-folders itself.

Comment: Still, this is unsupported. I wish you could do this as well. With a custom UI, you can end up with a LOT of layouts and drawable resources in one folder. Hopefully they add this in a future release of the SDK>

Comment: Marked as answer as this technically correct, this is not currently possible. I'm exploring alternative such as packaging up my views into separate projects.

Answer (score 18):

Another option is to use a prefix for your different views. Is not as nice as having different folder but it can introduce some order.

Answer (score 9):

Now with Android Studio and Gradle, you can have multiple resource folders in your project. Allowing to organize not only your layout files but any kind of resources.

It's not exactly a sub-folder, but may separte parts of your application.

The configuration is like this:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res', 'src/main/res2']
    }
}
```

Check the [documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/resource-merging).

Comment: filename will conflict though.

Comment: hello, I tryied your solution but when running build it says: Could not find property 'res' on source set 'main'.

Comment: Did u try adding the sourceSets insude the android {...} block?