# Android: Layout Issue for HTC EVO 3d

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, android-emulator, android-relativelayout

First off all my question is which layout is supported by the HTC EVO 3d ?
I am going to build the universal app. 
I have set the layout for all devices by following : [Supporting Multiple Screen](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Now the resolution for the HTC Evo 3d is 540X960. I have also made the imulator with that configuration but while i am going to run the app, the result is not showing good so i am wonder about how to set the layout that support all screen + HTC Evo 3d also.

So need help regarding this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not make universal application with same look on every device.As from the android developer describe

```
xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp
```

Let pick small screen.Its start from  426dp x 320dp and up to  470dp x 320dp(till normal screens came).If we are setting text and font or image for  426dp x 320dp and running app on 
469dpx320dp then it will affect result some how(it should not as both are part of small screen).This difference increase from`m-dpi to l-dpi`.So we can not remove the effect of that but we can reduce it.If you make universal app then it can not be perfect any how

[See Details about densiites](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: I have not done it before but see this may you get some idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571079/android-organise-layouts-into-sub-folders.I have done it for landscape and portrait and it work fine