# Android: Layout trying to insert 3 textviews across and 3 squares down

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to create 3 textviews across and 3 textviews down (totaly of 9 textboxes) evenly spaced and when the screen is changed i.e. Landscape and size of screen that they move to adjust the spaces between but the size of the textviews stay the same.

I am real issues i have tried a Linear layout but could get that to work, and then a relative layout neither ... i think the right one is table... but i just can't get it to work.

Can anyone help, i know this must be possible.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you gave up on RelativeLayout try GridLayout ;)

or better - Vertical LinearLayout filled with three Horizontal LinearLayouts...

However you might wanna use different layout folders to specify which one to use
So in landscape you will one layout and in portrait you use a different layout (both using the same name, located in layout-land and layout-port folders)

[Android layout folders: layout, layout-port, layout-land](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5407752/android-layout-folders-layout-layout-port-layout-land)

[Android Organise Layouts into Sub Folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571079/android-organise-layouts-into-sub-folders)

I guess it's the even-spacing that gets you, which is why you might wanna try and do it by using a vertical layout filled with horizonal layouts...